# Use fixtures in integration tests

Tags: php, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I found that CakePhp 3 use real db connection in integration tests, so line like `$this->post('articles/delete/1')` delete the real db row even if fixtures provided. Is it possible to use only data provided by fixtures (test connection)? Model tests are working normally with fixtures using test connection.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP performs the following during the course of a fixture based test case:

```
1. Creates tables for each of the fixtures needed.
2. Populates tables with data, if data is provided in fixture.
3. Runs test methods.
4. Empties the fixture tables.
5. Removes fixture tables from database.
```

So as mentioned in cake's [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html) cakephp empties the fixture tables and no matter either it delete records or save records or do any other operation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for my problem.

In my bootstrap.php I had event listener binded to app events. In listener's constructor I initialized properties with models objects using TableRegistry::get().

The reason was that TableRegistry will remember connection to use on first call so that then ConnectionManager::alias() will have no effect. As I had TableRegistry initialization in my event's constructor it was called before main app loaded and fixtureManager added connection aliases.

So never call TableRegistry before app loaded or it may cause problems.